# Under which circumstances might std::unique_ptr::operator[] throw?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unique-ptr, noexcept

I have an `operator[]` for my class and all it does is call `std::unique_ptr::operator[]` on a `unique_ptr` member. The relevant part is just this:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {
    T& operator [](const size_t pos) const noexcept
    {
        return data_[pos];
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;
};
```

I've marked the operator as `noexcept`. However, `unique_ptr::operator[]` is *not* `noexcept`. I am unable to find out why that is, and whether I can just assume that it will never throw. `unique_ptr::operator[]` itself does not list any exceptions in the documentation (cppreference and MSDN claim it does not define any list of exceptions it might throw.)

So I assume the missing `noexcept` might either be: a) a mistake, or b) the underlying datatype accessed by the operator might throw. Option a would be nice, since that would mean I can mark my own operator `noexcept`. Option b would be difficult to understand, since all the operator does it get a reference and it doesn't call anything.

So, long story short, is there any possibility of `unique_ptr::operator[]` ever throwing, and is it safe to call it from a `noexcept` function?

Comment: Well `unique_ptr::operato[]` just applies `operator[]` to the underlying pointer, right? That can easily lead to undefined behavior if the index is too big, so who knows what could happen...

Comment: @DeiDei That would be UB, but not throwing.

Comment: @DeiDei `unique_ptr` doesn't do a range check (and it lacks an `at()` member), so when the access is outside the range, it will not throw. In fact, I don't think it even keeps track of the current size, so it couldn't check and throw even if it wanted to.

Comment: @vsoftco *undefined behaviour* means anything can happen, including throwing an exception.  For example some common implementations of `std::vector` throw for out-of-range access, in debug mode.

Comment: @M.M Knew about the debug mode. However, then you're saying that every function that may potentially invoke UB should be not marked `noexcept`?

Comment: Not saying anything like that.

Comment: Perhaps the rationale for not making it `noexcept` is to allow implementations to do bounds-checking and throw. You can still make your wrapper `noexcept`, it just means that if the `[]` does throw then the application is likely to terminate.

Comment: The non-array `unique_ptr`'s `get()` returns a user-defined type `Deleter::pointer` (in general case), and unique_ptr<T[]>::operator[] is specified to call `get()[]`, so it would be calling a user-defined function...  except the array unique_ptr actually requires that `pointer` is the same as `T*`

Comment: @Cubbi Does it? It's still `typedef see below pointer;`. If I understand correctly, if the `unique_ptr` is constructed with an argument of the same type as `pointer`, it doesn't need to be `element_type*`. Actual pointers are only required in order to support qualification conversions between different types. However, I guess we could say that, array or non-array, if no custom deleter is specified, `pointer` is guaranteed to be `T*`, and that's actually OP's case.

Comment: @bogdan what I was referring to is that array form's constructors don't participate in overload resolution if pointer is not element_type*.. but since I am not sure, I am not writing an answer.

Comment: @Cubbi As far as I understand, the ones like `template <class U> explicit unique_ptr(U p) noexcept;` do participate in overload resolution if `U` is the same type as `pointer`, even if `pointer` is not `T*`, according to [20.8.1.3.1] (for the array version). It's just the trickier ones involving conversions that require `element_type*`. Unless I'm missing something, of course.

Comment: I was utterly confused myself when i saw this, but then i noticed that all of the `operator[]` overloads don't actually have the `noexcept` specifier in the stl, really curious as to why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, long story short, is there any possibility of unique_ptr::operator[] ever throwing

Yes. It will simply use `[]` on the pointer type that it has. And that could throw. Recall that, thanks to deleter gymnastics, the pointer type need not be an actual pointer. It could be a user-defined object type with its own `operator[]` overload that could throw on out-of-bounds use.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I give it a try (I am not sure of the answer).

I went through the [noexcept reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) and my understanding is that `noexcept` is simply indicating that the function *should* not throw exception, so that the compiler *could* make more agressive optimisations.
As to why the `unique_ptr::operator[]` is not `noexcept` I *guess* that the one standardising imagined that some implementors may throw and some other may not.
My opinion is that `unique_ptr::operator[]` may be throwing depending on the implementation of `unique_ptr` (typically when the index is out of bound).
However depending of the context of your code you could make sure this won't happen and decide to specify `noexcept` for your operator[].

Comment: "*my understanding is that noexcept is simply indicating that the function should not throw exception*" How do you get that understanding from that link? It says very clearly, "If a search for a matching exception handler leaves a function marked noexcept or noexcept(true), std::terminate is called immediately." Or in plain language, if you try to throw an exception out of a `noexcept` function, `std::terminate` will be called. That's not a "should not"; it's a "*can* not".

Comment: @NicolBolas , i found it in the notes near the end of the page.

Comment: @NicolBolas, sorry my mystake, I was thinking that of my *should* at compile time.